# How do Chrome app icons work?

Tags: chrome, icons, .desktop

This is fairly trivial question, but I’m curious about how this works.

I just wanted to change an icon used by a Chromium App created from a web address. The `.desktop` file refers to an icon with a name made from the app id…

```
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium --profile-directory=Default --app-id=ocdlmjhbenodhlknglojajgokahchlkk
Icon=chrome-ocdlmjhbenodhlknglojajgokahchlkk-Default
```

…but there is no icon with this name that I can find in `$HOME/.icons` (just a link to…), `$HOME/.local/share/icons`, `/usr/local/share/icons`, `/usr/share/icons` or `/usr/share/pixmaps`.

I did eventually find them in dedicated app folders under `$HOME/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions` but they don’t have the names referenced in the `.desktop` file (e.g. 32.png, 64.png) so how does the system find them?

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice if there is a `$HOME/.local/share/icons/hicolor` directory?
It's where third party applications should store their icons, following the FreeDesktop specifications
(if you need more information regarding this matter, you can find it at https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#directory_layout )

Inside that folder you can find other folders with various size; I guess most the icons are on the 128x128 format, even though some have bigger and smaller size

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).